# How to putExtra data from strings.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a lot of strings in my strings.xml, I want to putExtra to another intent where the data that I retrieve is taken from strings.xml, but when the application is run it doesn't get the results I want

sender activity

```
Intent moveIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, informationActivity.class);
moveIntent.putExtra(informationActivity.data1, "@string/THISISMYSTRINGFROMSTRINGSXML");
startActivity(moveIntent);
```

recipient intent

```
String data1= getIntent().getStringExtra(data1);
text1.setText(data1);
```

and the results that I got were

```
@string/THISISMYSTRINGFROMSTRINGSXML
```

I think by providing data like the above will make the text that appears taken from the strings.xml file, apparently not, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: use fun for getting the res -> for string use `getString(R.string.THISISMYSTRINGFROMSTRINGSXML)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the string by:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.string_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getString method to fetch the actual string.
Like below

```
String str = getString(R.string.<string-name>);
putString(<key>, str);
```

Then fetch using

```
intent.getString(<key>)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`@string/foo` returns an int which is basically just a reference. To get an exact string value, use:

```
context.getString(R.string.string_name);
```

If you're implementing this inside a class that extends Activity or its subclass, you can do it this way.

```
getString(R.string.string_name);
```

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent moveIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, informationActivity.class);
moveIntent.putExtra(informationActivity.data1,getResources().getString(R.string.string_name));
startActivity(moveIntent);
```